# 2 concurrent requests data from API were mixed up

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was using Nodejs as the backend of my app's API, but I realized that when there are 2 different users keep on requesting on the same method, the data return from MySQL requests might mixed up sometimes, here is my code:

```
router.get('/v1/getList', function(req, res) {
    model.getList(loginUser, function(groups){
        if(!groups.length){
            res.json({data: '', success: false, message: 'No record found.'});
        } else{
            console.log("User:"+loginUser+", Length:"+groups.length);
            res.json({data: groups, success: true, message: ''});                    
        }
    });
});
```

`loginUser` is the user ID. In normal condition the terminal output will be like below, which User 1 have 2 items and User 2 have 3 items:

```
User:1, Length:2
User:2, Length:3
User:1, Length:2
User:2, Length:3
and so on...
```

But once I keep refreshing the screen and the terminal might return:

```
User:1, Length:2
User:2, Length:3
User:1, Length:3
User:2, Length:2
```

Which I suspect the data request by User 2 was being access by User 1 and vice versa, may I know how should I fix this?

Comment: Where does `loginUser` come from.  If it's a module level or global level variable, then that's a no-no for a node.js app.  You likely need to be getting `loginUser` from a login session object that is specific to the current request (so it will not get confused when there are multiple requests going on at once).

Comment: where do you store `loginUser` ? is it different  for the users ? or is it getting overwritten ?

Comment: @jfriend00 @Oxi Yes `loginUser` is a global variable, its value was set using a middleware which whenever the API request contains of `v1` it will decodes the access token and store the respective user ID into `loginUser` this variable, is it I should add a `var` in front of `loginUser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use global variables to store `loginUser` from middleware.  There can be multiple requests in flight at the same time.  Uisng a global like this mixes the data from multiple requests.

The usual way to solve this issue is to store your data in the `request` object itself from your middleware.  You can then access that property on the `request` object from your actual request handler.  Since the request object is unique to this specific request, there is no cross coupling of data between requests from different users.

Your request handler becomes this (using `req.loginUser`):

```
router.get('/v1/getList', function(req, res) {
    model.getList(req.loginUser, function(groups){
        if(!groups.length){
            res.json({data: '', success: false, message: 'No record found.'});
        } else{
            console.log("User:"+loginUser+", Length:"+groups.length);
            res.json({data: groups, success: true, message: ''});                    
        }
    });
});
```

And, you have to modify your middleware to set `req.loginUser` rather than the global variable.

Comment: Yes it solved my issue! Thank you very much! One more question, when the request was sent using `socket.emit`, I have to decode the access token manually without using middleware, so there is no `request` object, how should I fix it then?

Comment: @Ping - Sorry, but I don't understand what you're asking with this new issue.  You can attach properties to the `socket` object itself if that's relevant.  You never use globals for request-specific storage in node.js because that ruins your ability to process requests from multiple users.