# Would the values inside request be mixed up in callback?

Tags: node.js, express, callback

I am new to Node.js, and I have been reading questions and answers related with this issue, but still not very sure if I fully understand the concept in my case.

**Suggested Code**

```
router.post('/test123', function(req, res) { 
someAsyncFunction1(parameter1, function(result1) {
  someAsyncFunction2(parameter2, function(result2) {
    someAsyncFunction3(parameter3, function(result3) {
       var theVariable1 = req.body.something1;
       var theVariable2 = req.body.something2;
    )}
  )}
});
```

**Question**
I assume there will be multiple (can be 10+, 100+, or whatever) requests to one certain place (for example, ajax request to /test123, as shown above) at the same time with some variables (something1 and something2). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239692/2-concurrent-requests-data-from-api-were-mixed-up), it would be impossible that one user's theVariable1 and theVariable2 are mixed up with (i.e, overwritten by) the other user's req.body.something1 and req.body.something2. I am wondering if this is true when there are multiple callbacks (three like the above, or ten, just in case).

And, I also consider using res.locals to save some data from callbacks (instead of using theVariable1 and theVariable2, but is it good idea to do so given that the data will not be overwritten due to multiple simultaneous requests from clients?

Comment: Yes, it is impossible that the variables get mixed up. `function`s are scoped in JS.

Comment: The overall question is a bit confusing, so forgive me if I misunderstand you. Each user would be issuing a separate HTTP request, so their code will not collide, thus variables will not be mixed up between users.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! That is exactly what I would like to ask.

Comment: You can also use `res.locals` to persist data locally (in the request scope): http://expressjs.com/es/4x/api.html#res.locals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each request an Node.js/Express server gets generated a new `req` object.

So in the line `router.post('/test123', function(req, res)`, the `req` object that's being passed in as an argument is unique to that HTTP connection.

You don't have to worry about multiple functions or callbacks. In a traditional application, if I have two objects `cat` and `dog` that I can pass to the `listen` function, I would get back `meow` and `bark`. Even though there's only one `listen` function. That's sort of how you can view an Express app. Even though you have all these `get` and `post` functions, every user's request is passed to them as a unique entity.